# Firebase Hosting at Index.html, I want Index.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, deployment

So I built a react app, works mainly how I wanted, but I wanted to involve firebase. So I set it up and followed the instructions, it deploys properly, except it deploys to index.html, but the app would be index.js.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that runs into this issue, you need to change the public line in `firebase.json` to

```
...
"hosting": {
  "public : "build",
...
```

Then use `npm run build` to make a new build of the project, followed by `firebase deploy`